# underextrusion of infill?

Tags: print-quality, infill, underextrusion

Running a bency print to test my new cooler, I noticed an odd effect on the rectilinear infill I'm using:

[image]
[image]

It's almost as if the individual lines of the infill are tearing. The thing is that the actual print turned out great, so the solid layers end up cleaning up the mess and being good. I'm wondering if this is a matter of my infill speed being too fast? I'm running 90mm/s for infill, and the next fastest setting is 70 (i think for perimeters).

Parameters: Tevo Tornado, 1.75mm PETG at 235C, bed at 85C. 100% cooling through the petsfang cooler starting from layer 3.

Comment: Reduce the cooling, PETG does not need 100 % cooling. What speeds do you print infill?

Comment: Infill at 90. I'll try reducing the cooling.

Comment: That is too fast, reduce to 50-60 mm/s PETG does not like being printed fast. Cooling at least half, but depends on the type and effectiveness of cooling. See [this answer to a similar question](/a/8233/).

Comment: Hi there, if this isn't a duplicate and has been incorrectly closed,  please flag as such, and I'll gladly reopen it.  :-)

Comment: @Greenonline no worries - thanks. It's close enough, though didn't come up in search.